# Getting a hosting provider if i use NoSQL technologies

Tags: hosting, dedicated-server, nosql

My current system is being developed in codeignitor and MySQL. But we are adding Redis, Solr and either Cassandra or mongodb for some data structure storage. So the big question i am lost now if this makes the web hosting choice different vs if i only had MySQL?

All the hosting plans i see offer only the OS & hardware choice, there is no mention on the databases so i am not sure if the requirements are different.

Environment is a cloud or VPS for staging and dedicated enviornment with CDN for production.

Answer (score 3):

IF you are buying (renting) a dedicated server, it is your responsibility for installing the SQL storage system. **They are responsible for the network and hardware, and you for the software.** That is, unless you work out some sort of management with them - then they can be tasked with installing the SQL server for you, whether it be NoSQL or MySQL or HarpoonDB.*

Roughly the same for cloud.

** Note, HarpoonDB does not exist*

Comment: HarpoonDB does not exist *yet*